# Swift - Dismiss search controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, uisearchcontroller

I'm currently trying to implement a search functionality over a `UITableView` with dynamic data retrieved from an API call.

The flow would be something like this

1. Press the right bar button item (search functionality)
2. A search controller is **presented** over the table view.
3. The user enters some text on it and presses the search button
4. The controller performs an API call based on the user's search.
5. The table view gets populated with the results.

I've seen sokme examples on how to implement search over a tableView, and I think mine is different, because I manually present the search controller. It's not shown until the search button is pressed (as opossite to the examples, when `UISearch` is added to table header view and the search functionality is triggered when the user taps over the search bar.)

So basically I've got some questions:
1.- Is my approach iOS-friendly? Maybe I cannot find resources about how I'm trying to achieve because It's not.
2.- If true, how can I dismiss the search controller after the search button on the keyboard is pressed?
3.- How can I distinguish between a dismissal fired by the search button on keyboard or by the cancel button on search bar?

Here's my code so far:

```
extension MyTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
  }
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate {
  var searchController: UISearchController!
  var data = [CoolData]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "search"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: .SearchTapped)
  }

  func searchButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.translucent = false
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: BACConstants.color.Yellow)
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: BACConstants.color.Black)
    self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

}

private extension Selector {
  static let SearchTapped = #selector(InvolvedProcessesViewController.searchButtonTapped(_:))
}
```

Comment: Actually you can refer to code provided by Apple to accomplish this. Run the sample code and it is under Search -> Present Over Navigation Bar section. Here's the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I've read the swift example on this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UIKitCatalog_SearchPresentOverNavigationBarViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710-Swift_UIKitCatalog_SearchPresentOverNavigationBarViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_77

It seems to explain how to present the search bar, but not how to handle its events.

But at least now I know that it's iOS-friendly, since it's on the official examples. :)

Answer (score 2):

assuming you are using `UITableViewController`, you can add a `UISearchController` like this:

```
var shouldShowSearchResults = false
var searchController: UISearchController!

func configureSearchController() {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

then, implement this two delegates: `UISearchResultsUpdating`, `UISearchBarDelegate`

```
 // MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // do your thing
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // do your thing
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // do your thing
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercaseString

    // do your thing..

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this assumes that I want to display a search bar over the table, and trigger the search functionality there. In my case, the search is triggered by pressing a UIBarButtonItem over the Navigation controller that holds the tableview.

Comment: Well, taking your answer I've finally managed to do it, I just had to make a little tweak to adapt it to my case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Taking @matias-elorriaga answer I've finally made it. I was using the wrong delegate to handle my search events.

```
extension MyTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
  }
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
  var searchController: UISearchController!
  var data = [CoolData]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "search"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: .SearchTapped)
  }

  func searchButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.translucent = false
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: BACConstants.color.Yellow)
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: BACConstants.color.Black)
    self.presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }    

  func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.searchController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) // When search is tapped, dismiss the search and fetch the results based on the filter 
  }
}

private extension Selector {
  static let SearchTapped = #selector(InvolvedProcessesViewController.searchButtonTapped(_:))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.searchController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```